# NavigationLink within view presented as an overlay. SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I am presenting a view as an overlay but when I add a NavigationLink with a destination to that overlay view, the text is greyed out and tapping it does nothing. How do I proceed?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView { }
        .overlay(
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Go to some view")) {
                    Text("NavigationLink in overlay")
                }
                Button {
                    print("button tapped")
                } label: {
                    Text("Button in overlay")
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The best way to proceed is by posting a minimal reproducible example in your question.

Comment: @HunterLion just updated with an example and image.

Comment: @HunterLion as you can see, the navigation link is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your NavigationLink is not inside the NavigationView! Try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Color.clear
                .overlay(
                    VStack {
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Go to some view")) {
                            Text("NavigationLink in overlay")
                        }
                        Button {
                            print("button tapped")
                        } label: {
                            Text("Button in overlay")
                        }
                    }
                )
        }
    }
}
```